# Remove Azure Licence for user from a csv file

Tags: azure, powershell

I don't know why my script work just for the first line and then I have :

> ```
> Get-MsolUser : Impossible de convertir «System.Object[]» en type «System.String», requis par le paramètre «UserPrincipalName». La 
> méthode spécifiée n'est pas prise en charge.
> Au caractère Ligne:5 : 34
> + (get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $csv2).licenses.AccountSkuId |
> +                                  ~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Get-MsolUser], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.GetUser
> ```

My Code :

```
$csv2 = Import-Csv C:\Tools\LicencesToRemove.csv
for ($i=0; $i -lt $csv2.Count; $i++)
{
(get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $csv2).licenses.AccountSkuId |foreach{
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $csv2 -RemoveLicenses $_
}
}
```

csv file :

> ```
> test.delete1@abc.onmicrosoft.com
> test.delete2@abc.onmicrosoft.com
> test.delete3@abc.onmicrosoft.com
> test.delete4@abc.onmicrosoft.com
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here.

```
get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $csv2
```

The `UserPrincipalName` must be of [type `string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0#example-3--get-a-user-by-upn) where as here it is `Object[]`. I suspect you are intended to write the following within the `for` loop

```
get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $csv2[$i].YourCsvColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your .csv2 file has a header with "UserPrincipalName". You can use the script below.

```
    $csv2 = Import-Csv C:\Tools\LicencesToRemove.csv
    foreach($user in $csv2)
    {
    (get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName).licenses.AccountSkuId |foreach{
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses $_
    }
    }
```